# jQuery on second click—anywhere on the page—toggleClass again

Tags: jquery

I'm having some serious difficulties with a concept that seems relatively straight-forward.

I have two buttons side by side, Sort and Filter. When one is clicked, two things happen:

1. The class **menu-is-open** is toggled on the button in order to show or hide the button's menu.
2. The class **is-visible** is removed from the opposite button to make certain the two menus are never open at the same time.

This works great.

Now I want the second click, if it is on a menu item or anywhere on the webpage, to again toggle (close) the **menu-is-open** class on the active button. But there is an exception, if the other button (Filter or Sort) is clicked with that second click, I want it to function that same way it does now (open the button's menu and close the active button's menu).

```
var sortResults = $('#bitSort'),
    filterResults = $('#bitFilter'),
    sortItems = sortResults.find('#cd-main-nav ul'),
    filterItems = filterResults.find('#cd-main-nav ul');

//opens or closes the menu when clicking on the SORT button
sortResults.find('.bitTrigger').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-is-open');
    //remove the transitionEnd event handler and FILTER menu if open
    sortItems.off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend').toggleClass('is-visible');
    filterItems.removeClass('is-visible');
});

//opens or closes the menu clicking on the FILTER button
filterResults.find('.bitTrigger').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-is-open');
    //remove the transitionEnd event handler and SORT menu if open
    filterItems.off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend').toggleClass('is-visible');
    sortItems.removeClass('is-visible');
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post JSfiddle

Comment: It should be set to trigger when the menu is blurred. Setting it to trigger "on anything clicked" is intrusive to the page and will likely be a headache if it triggers based on element that appears to be child in the UI.

Comment: @Anthony, I see where you're coming from. But I find in most cases, when a user wants to exit an open menu, closing the menu by clicking anywhere off or on the menu is an expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add a click hander to the document

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('#bitFilter .bitTrigger, #bitSort .bitTrigger').length) {
        return;
    }
    $('#bitSort .bitTrigger, #bitFilter .bitTrigger').removeClass('menu-is-open');
    filterItems.removeClass('is-visible');
    sortItems.removeClass('is-visible');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5udufzd7/)

Comment: Arun, that did the trick! Had to make a minor typo correction and it worked as requested. Thank you! If you ever have the time, I'd greatly appreciate if you could breakdown the click handler you made. It's a bit confusing to me. In any case, thank you.

Comment: @user3775937 I think the only problem is in the `if` condition... if so it just checks whether the target of teh click was either the `#bitFilter .bitTrigger` or  `#bitSort .bitTrigger`... if so don't do anyting else... remove the active conditions from all elements

Comment: Got it! Why did you add .length to your if statement? I don't understand that part.

Comment: @user3775937 if the closest returns a matching element the the .length will be > 0 which is a truthy value so the control will enter the `if` block